# EF on NET.CORE dbcontext not loading in WPF page on

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, entity-framework-core, datacontext

A system in NET.Core 3.1 and WPF has the following DbContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

The ConfigureDervices in App.xaml.cs is as follows:

```
private void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));
        
        services.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
    }
```

It navigates to the page:

```
public partial class AuthenticationService : Page, IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public AuthenticationService(DataContext context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _context = context;
    }

    private void OkBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var usuario = AuthenticateUser(EmailTb.Text, SenhaTb.Text);
    }

    public Usuario AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var usuario = _context.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username.Equals(username)
            && u.HashedPassword.Equals(CalculateHash(u.Username, password)));

        ...

        return usuario;
    }

    public string CalculateHash(string clearTextPassword, string salt)
    { 
        ...
    }

}
```

debbuging to the line:

```
    var usuario = _context.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username.Equals(username)
            && u.HashedPassword.Equals(CalculateHash(u.Username, password)));
```

shows that _context is null.

How do I get a valid context?

Comment: are your connection string is true ?

Comment: Yes... With it I built the whole database with migrations...

Comment: please try this :
public AuthenticationService(DataContext context)
{
     _context = context;
     InitializeComponent();
}

set context before init

Comment: Nope... Still the same thing...

Comment: I suggest create repository for your authorize and use DI for inject

Comment: just in case, put directly connection string as argument. let see what's happening

Comment: _context is still null... No change..

Comment: Try it later, it will disappear :))

Comment: @AkbarAsghari the OP is already doing that. Using another repository on top of the repository-like DataContext won't fix anything

Comment: @SergioDiFiore where/how are you instantiating `AuthenticationService`? If you instantiate it through DI, you'd get an error if the container was unable to create a DataContext. If you create it explicitly, the value passed to the constructor is null, for one reason or another. Add a null-check to the constructor and check *why* the context passed there is null

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you made a very good point... Before that I was considering that the declaration in the ConfigureServices: services.AddDbContext<DataContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=GALILEO;Database=SeqLex;Trusted_Connection=True;")); was doing the DI... Now I assume that it doesn't...  Thus I'm completely lost...

Comment: This registers the services and classes so it can provide them when you request them. Where *do* you request that page? How and where do you create it? Is it created by some MVVM library in response to navigation perhaps? Which one? The MVVM library has to know about DI to use it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't use MVVM, just code behind. It's supposed to be some very simple stuff...  A the ConfigureServices I use the line "services.AddDbContext<DataContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=GALILEO;Database=SeqLex;Trusted_Connection=True;"));" where I believe will handle the injection (actually, I'm not sure) and on the click that calls it it's used: "_mainFrame.Navigate(new AuthenticationService());" And that's basically it!

Comment: `new AuthenticationService()`? First, that means there's another constructor that wasn't included in the questin and second, it means *your own code* calls the wrong constructor. You need to call `new AuthenticationService(someContext)` where  `someContext` is a valid context instance

Comment: That's the syntax I'm trying to figure it out... Because I, until now, assumed that the depency injection mechanis from asp.net core would to the trick...

Comment: You are *not* using DI in your code, you're constructing the instance directly. This isn't about syntax. To use DI you need to ask the service collection for an instance. Assuming `AuthenticationService` is also registered, you should use  `services.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationService>()`